How to import gazebo world into gym gazebo?
I've created my gazebo world included .world file, urdf files for models and bot, some plugin packages (realsense for gazebo) and .launch file. How can I register it as an environment in gym gazebo for reinforcement learning. I couldn't find a tutorial for gazebo import as most of them uses pygame (despite there are literally several official examples using gazebo like GazeboCircuit2TurtlebotLidar-v0).
